# Filtering with IntegerList on JasperServer Reports and Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying to use parameters in Jasper Reports but I'm getting some difficult using list, more precisely Integer List.

I have a Postgres procedure that receives an integer array as parameter like this query `select * from function_x(array[n1,n2,n3])`. But I don't know how send this values as a Postgres Array.

I already set the param to **Multi Select Query** in JasperServer.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added MacGyver:

```xml
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from function_x(array$P!{PARAMETER})]]>
</queryString>
```

Postgres accept `array[]` or `{}` as **array values** and the problem is that the Jasper was trying to send `[n1,n2,n3] (string)` so what I done was concatenate `array` with `[]`.

That solved my problem...